# Can people feel somebody is watching them?

Tags: psychology, environment

I think most of us is familiar with this feeling. You can tell someone (who stands behind your back) is staring at you without any physical evidence.

Is it possible or is it just a matter of coincidence? How is this phenomena called? Was it ever proven or disproven?

Comment: As an avid SCUBA diver of 500+ dives, I have distinctly noticed that divers _fail_ to turn to see objects (other divers, fish, etc.) outside their FOV. This difference in behavior is so clearcut that I have come to believe that the feeling of being looked at arises from either subliminal hearing or touch (air currents). Purely anecdotal, of course.

Comment: Hah, I stared at you for three hours through the window while you sat at your computer, but you *never* noticed me.

Comment: No wonder my ears were burning -- I've been keeping my eyes on you lately!  8-D

Comment: Background Wikipedia reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychic_staring_effect

Comment: From personal experience, there are many times when I turned around and **nobody** was there - this could be confirmation bias

Comment: Interestingly enough, if someone is within your line of sight there is a [gaze detection system](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-narcissus-in-all-us/201102/how-you-know-eyes-are-watching-you) that could trigger the "being watched" feeling that people sometimes describe.

Comment: @Phoshi Isn't that the opposite of confirmation bias?

Comment: @Sancho: Confirmation bias would be one remembering the times it happened, because they're notable, and forgetting the ones that did not, because they are not.

Comment: @Phoshi Yes, that is confirmation bias. I got confused about the previous wording since you are saying you remember the many times when nobody was there.

Comment: @Sancho: Ah, I see. I was saying that while I remember turning around to nobody, others may not, and the phenomenon can be explained with confirmation bias.

Comment: There is no proof of that, however your mind constantly detects subliminal perceptions in the world around you, it can be seeing the shape of a face looking at you, and this unconscious perception is not unlikely to trigger, rightly or wrongly the thought of being watched.

Comment: I couldn't find any studies that that disprove that the feeling can be caused by subliminally perceptions of someone noticing you. Therefore, it has not been scientifically disproved, that such feelings are sometimes accurately provoked by unconciously noticing that someone is watching you.

Comment: What about other animals? can rabbits and deer feel that they are being watched? if they could they would have a better chance of survival. so perhaps they think it as much is is sanely reasonable.

Comment: Personally I believe it is more due to presence than "being looked at". But I also believe it is more due to sublime changes in ambient sound and such that triggers that "feeling". Yes, personal idea, yet I know there have been times where I've felt -something- turned and found a person behind\near me. Tho, this is a lot more clear when you THINK you are alone.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are some (in)famous experiments done by Rupert Sheldrake who claims that a so-called "morphogenetic" field is responsible for this sort of thing. Alas, his experiments had quite sloppy methodology.

The feeling itself is real, as most here will testify. But it has nothing to do with being *actually* stared at/observed.

http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=ruperts-resonance

Apart from some technical problems with Sheldrake's experiment, here is a partial explanation for why some people really believe they can feel when they are stared at:

> Second, psychologists dismiss anecdotal accounts of this sense to a reverse self-fulfilling effect: a person suspects being stared at and turns to check; such head movement catches the eyes of would-be starers, who then turn to look at the staree, who thereby confirms the feeling of being stared at.
>   [...]
>   When University of Hertfordshire psychologist Richard Wiseman also attempted to replicate Sheldrake's research, he found that subjects detected stares at rates no better than chance.

So the conclusion is **no**, people cannot *really* feel somebody is watching them.

Comment: That alone is not really enough for a good conclusion. Just because an experiment that is suggesting this effect had some issues, it does not by itself mean that the results were wrong. This needs more evidence.

Comment: @Cray, given the claim is extraordinary (by what mechanism could a person detect the gaze direction of someone outside of their field of view?), it is reasonable to continue to provisionally accept the null hypothesis until extraordinary evidence is provided.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Vision isn't the only sense. Both hearing and smelling could do something. The person who's viewing might change his breathing rate or emit pheromones because he's entering a social interaction.

Comment: I think even those who researched on this failed to understanding what part of the claim they ought to investigate and that is, what causes one to turn there head in the first place (or suspect that they are being watched). The conclusion doesn't seem to explain this feeling, it only explains why it appears that somebody was watching you.

Comment: Sounds like measurement bias to me.

Answer (score 37):

Cornell psychologist [Edward Titchener](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_B._Titchener) (who studied under [Wundt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilhelm_Wundt)) tested the ability to detect *unseen* staring and published in [Science (1898)](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/8/208/895.short). His conclusion: people cannot detect when they are being stared at, though a great many believe they can.

Though others have tested this `ability' over the years (e.g., [Rupert Sheldrake](http://www.sheldrake.org/experiments/staring/)), the results are mixed, and when statistically significant results are got, this is usually because of sloppy procedure.

Titchener would be rolling in his grave to know this sh*t is still being discussed.

Here's a short summary ([source](http://www.everythingispointless.com/2006/12/stop-staring-at-me.html)):

> [Titchener] reported that over the years he had conducted a large number of informal tests and found no evidence for this particular claim. As far as Titchener was concerned people were not able to demonstrate their widely held belief.
>
> He went on to provide a very good normal explanation for why people have this belief. First he noted that **humans have forward facing vision**, which **leaves us exposed to the rear** and he suggested that when in a situation where you are forced to present your back to a group of people, that there **may be some psychological discomfort in that**. He went as far to say that our ancestors must surely have devoted constant care to the defence of their backs. Titchener claimed that this back vigilance is the first element of staring detection: that people protect their backs by being aware of the environment behind them.
>
> Once the feeling to turn around has formed, it is followed by an executing of the behavioural component: turning the head around and examining the back environment. Attention moves across the back of the room, scanning it to update their information as to what is actually going on.
>
> Titchener next turned his attention to what might be happening behind the individual. He noted that his students could be engaged in a range of different behaviours (playing with their hair, eating food etc) and that it should be expected that some of the people sitting behind may be staring in the general direction of the individual. When they turn around, they disturb the visual field for those people who happen to have been looking in their general direction. This movement is a strong stimulus for people sitting behind, which they are required to attend to. There may in fact be any number of people who have the person in their visual field and who suddenly respond to the movement of the person looking around.
>
> It is this coincidence which Titchener argued is the basis for the belief. Why do people feel the special tingling in their neck though? Titchener remarked that **this no different from the feeling experienced in the bottom after sitting down for a long time!**

Comment: This answer seems focused on secondhand "informal tests" and conjecture. The points are great, but did this guy actually _study_ the phenomenon or just watch people and sort of figure it out? The article you linked doesn't really do anything other than describe the situation and conclusion. I don't doubt he actually did study it but nothing here suggests so.

Comment: There is quite a lot of research into staring detection. I am not really very interested in giving a different answer or more complete answer. Just offering a perspective. I suggest not wasting time on it though...

Comment: @RSoul: The best way to stop us wasting time on this is to give a definitive answer, so we can move on, rather than "offering a perspective" that just encourages more people to offer a perspective.

Answer (score -2):

Here's the short description of the methodology adopted in several up-to-date researches, as it's described in [*Science Set Free: 10 Paths to New Discovery*
 by Rupert Sheldrake](http://books.google.fr/books?id=Q13qPII2VDUC&lpg=PA225&ots=-BW40cKwTS&dq=In%20direct-looking%20experiments%2C%20people%20work%20in%20pairs%2C%20with%20a%20subject%20and%20a%20looker&pg=PA225#v=onepage&q=In%20direct-looking%20experiments,%20people%20work%20in%20pairs,%20with%20a%20subject%20and%20a%20looker&f=false):

> "Since the 1980s the sense of being stared at has been investigated experimentally both through direct looking and also through closed circuit television (CCTV). In the scientific literature it is variously referred to as “unseen gaze detection” or “remote attention” or “scopaesthesia” (from Greek skopein, to view, and aisthetikos, sensitive).
>
> In direct-looking experiments, people work in pairs, with a subject and a looker. In a randomized series of trials, blindfolded subjects sit with their backs to the lookers, who either stare at the back of their necks, or look away and think of something else. A mechanical signal—a click or a beep—marks
>   the beginning of each trial. Within a few seconds the subjects guess whether they are being looked at or not. Their guesses are either right or wrong, and are recorded immediately. A test usually consists of twenty trials.
>   These tests are so simple that a child can do them, and thousands of children already have.
>
> In the 1990s, this research was popularized through New Scientist magazine, BBC TV and Discovery Channel TV, and many tests were conducted in schools and as student projects at universities. Altogether, tens of thousands of trials were carried out. The results were remarkably consistent.
>
> Typically, about 55 percent of the guesses were right, as opposed to 50 percent expected by chance. Although the effect was small, because it was so widely replicated it was highly significant statistically. In more rigorous experiments subjects and starers were separated by windows or one-way mirrors, eliminating the possibility of subtle cues by sound or even smell. They were still able to tell when they were being watched."

Dean Radin published a meta-analysis of 60 different super-visioned experiments conducted over 33,357 trial tests, titled [The Sense of Being Stared At: A Preliminary Meta-Analysis](http://www.deanradin.com/FOC2014/Radin2005MetaStaring.pdf). The result is a 54% chance of hit.

> It is clear that the mean hit rate stabilizes to just over 54%, where
>   50% is expected by chance. The FEM weighted mean effect size was significantly
>   above chance, *e* = 0.089 ± 0.003 (mean ± standard error), z = 32.5,
>   p = 10<sup>–232</sup>, and the distribution of effects was significantly heterogeneous,
>   Q = 763.3 (58 df), p = 10<sup>–232</sup>.

Comment: [Welcome to Skeptics!](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/welcome-to-new-users) 1)  Presumably you are referring to one of the other poorer answers. This isn't the place for comments on that answer.

Comment: 2) Please provide a cite for that quote. That quote doesn't, itself, provide references so it is a poor secondary source.

Comment: 3) Please link to Dean Radin's meta-analysis, so we can see it for ourselves. Radin's reputation as a researcher isn't strong, so we need to inspect it ourselves.

Comment: 4) "A 54% chance of hit. That's huge given the number of trials and chance probability of 50%." Such a statement needs statistic analysis. We need extraordinary proof to accept such an extraordinary claim which has no reasonable mechanism.

Comment: 5) ` "Null hypothesis until extraordinary evidence is provided" is for hard-sciences. For soft-sciences a 4% difference on the probability is a huge difference.' I'm afraid that is not just wrong, but insultingly so. Further, this is [hard science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_and_soft_science) so it is always irrelevant.

Comment: I improved to post to accommodate references. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: 4a) "Such a statement needs statistic analysis." Statistic analysis is made on Radin's Paper. The chance expectation is p = 10^–17. A chance probability so low is an extraordinary claim.

Comment: 4b) "a claim which has no reasonable mechanism". Quantum mechanics has no reasonable mechanism as well. ["Shut up and calculate!"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation).

Comment: 5) I didn't understand your comment. What is hard science? [Psychology is a soft science](http://articles.latimes.com/2012/jul/12/opinion/la-oe-wilson-social-sciences-20120712)

Comment: I edited, to reference the book from which the first quote was taken; and, to quote results directly from the second reference i.e. the PDF.

Comment: Is 4% a significant result? I think it is. I made a simple script in matlab to show that 60 disjoint coin-toss experiments using 60 trials (3600 samples total) is going to come very close to the 50-50% ratio. [Download script here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5919734/skeptic/randomSamplesCount.rar)

Comment: Statistically I'd guess it's significant if a) the tests are large with sufficiently-many coin tosses per test) b) the tests are fairly selected for the meta-study (not interesting if the meta-study discards all tests which have normal results) c) each test was fairly constructed/conducted.

Comment: Good points ChrisW. a) I think that sample used on the Meta-analysis is enough (can be verified using the Matlab script).

Comment: b) Looking for state-of-art papers I found 4 that don't find any evidence for staring effect: [1](http://www.transpersonal.gr/media/pdf/DA_&_conscious_EJP_2009.pdf), [2](http://archived.parapsych.org/papers/07.pdf), [3](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1348/000712605X80704/abstract), [4](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/237244298_REMOTE_STARING_DETECTED_BY_CONSCIOUS_AND_PSYCHOPHYSIOLOGICAL_VARIABLES_COMBINING_AND_IMPROVING_TWO_SUCCESSFUL_PARADIGMS).

Comment: However as noted in paper 1: "However in a post hoc analysis one of the conscious report variables approached significance for the interaction between staring and distraction in the predicted direction. The effect size of the staring effect in this condition was d = 0.57. We conclude that the starer’s mental strategy during the non-staring periods may be important".
Also 3 is made in collaboration with Dean Radin, which kinda makes the guy a little bit more credible.

Comment: Re: 5) Soft science. We are just arguing over definitions, which isn't terribly productive. The link you provide, however, demonstrates my point: some aspects of psychology make experimentally testable predictions. (By the link I provided, that makes those aspects a hard science.) Either way, your conclusion wasn't helpful; I've edited it away. We could also argue whether this is really psychology or "parapsychology", but again that's just about definitions, not facts.

Comment: 4b) A *lot* of experimental confirmation for quantum mechanics was required before it was accepted. If/when there is that much experimental confirmation is available for ESP, I am sure it, too, will be accepted.

Comment: 4a) Perhaps a better way of putting that is "According to [widely criticised and debunked claims by a notoriously poor researcher, Dean Radin,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dean_Radin), who 'ignored the known hoaxes in the field, made statistical errors and ignored plausible non-paranormal explanations for parapsychological data', the chance expectation is ..."

Comment: 4b) My point was that QM does not reasonable explanation so far, but no one questions its legitimism because of that.

Comment: 4a) Why use an _argument ad hominem_ when you can do better? You can download the papers that don't verify the staring effect and argue on that. Quoting Wikipedia to say that someone is doesn't have impeccable credentials is just dull.