# Do people know when they're being looked at?

Tags: psychology, environment

I've heard, and even once recall reading, that people have a sort of "6<sup>th</sup> sense" where they can tell if they're being looked at.

From personal experience, there were many times where I felt I was being watched, turned around, and indeed - someone was there.

So, is this just a coincidence, or is there any truth behind the claim?

Comment: Duplicate?  http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3049/can-people-feel-somebody-is-watching-them